# Formview control with table, controls in tr set to runat server do not insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

Here's an odd situation. In my `FormView` control, I put a `<table>` for layout. With the rows (`<tr>`) I added `ID`s and `runat="server"`. The insert only saved some of the data, which I thought was odd. I looked to see why those fields stored and others didn't, and the only difference was I hadn't added the `ID`s or `runat="server"` to the `<tr>`s. Removing the "runat" allowed the insert to work normally.

I assume this has something to do with the way the rows are initialized versus when the control or `FormView` is initialized. Any thoughts why this happens? For now, I'm removing the `ID`s from the table rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track in your thinking.

The `FormView` only looks at top-level controls.  If you embed one of your intended input controls inside of another server-side control, the `FormView` doesn't see it (it's been hidden inside the outer control).  Even in your code-behind you'd have to use the `FindControl` method to get the input tag out of the server-side `<tr>`

Thus, if you had this:

```
<tr ID="row1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="myTB" runat="server">12</asp:TextBox>
</tr>
```

The only thing the `FormView` sees is the top-level element (the `<tr>`).  You wouldn't even see the `TextBox` in your *codebehind* unless you did this:

```
TextBox myTB = (TextBox)row1.FindControl("myTB");
```

So my suggestion would be to leave off the "runat" and "ID" tags from the `<tr>` elements; since they are just for display purposes, you don't really need them at the server-side.

I hope that clears things up a little.

Comment: Will still have to play with this. I was using the tr to set that row visible or not... depending on other criteria. However, I can still check the textbox as you mentioned using FindControl.  Didn't realize that bit of info about the top-level elements.

Comment: @MKenyonII  Well I'm glad I was help to help (at least a little bit).  Good luck!